# Can't initialize new repository

Tags: git, netbeans, github, ide, bitbucket

I am having problems setting up a new rep with netbeans 8.0.1. After setting up the Git plugin, whenever I try to initialize a new repository, it gives me this error and stops the process.

This is the error that occurs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.netbeans.libs.git.GitBranch
at org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.repository.RepositoryInfo.<init>(RepositoryInfo.java:136)
at org.netbeans.modules.git.ui.repository.RepositoryInfo.getInstance(RepositoryInfo.java:156)
at org.netbeans.modules.git.Annotator.annotateFolderIcon(Annotator.java:373)
at org.netbeans.modules.git.Annotator.annotateIcon(Annotator.java:257)
at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.DelegatingVCS$2.annotateIcon(DelegatingVCS.java:243)
at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.core.VersioningAnnotationProvider$Cache.annotate(VersioningAnnotationProvider.java:658)
at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.core.VersioningAnnotationProvider$Cache.annotate(VersioningAnnotationProvider.java:688)
at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.core.VersioningAnnotationProvider$Cache.access$1500(VersioningAnnotationProvider.java:511)
at org.netbeans.modules.versioning.core.VersioningAnnotationProvider$Cache$AnnotationRefreshTask.run(VersioningAnnotationProvider.java:794)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

I already tried checking if the plugin was up to date, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution, pretty simple. I just rebooted Netbeans and all worked again.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a Git repository you need to complete the following steps:
1. In the Projects window, select an unversioned project and right-click the project name.
2. In the context menu, choose Versioning > Initialize Git Repository (alternatively, in the main menu, choose Team > Git > Initialize).
3. Specify the path to the repository you are going to store your versioned files in the Initialize a Git Repository dialog box or click Browse and browse for the directory required.
4. Click OK.
    A .git subfolder is created in the folder you specified in step 3 above (your NetBeans project folder by default), which is your Git repository where all the data of your project snapshots are stored. Git starts versioning all files in the folder you specified.
You can open Window > Output > Output to view the IDE's report about the progress of the repository creation under your local working directory.

All the project files are marked Added in your Working Tree. To view a file status, place the cursor over the file name in the Projects window. The status of the file in the Working Tree displays in green to the right of the slash like shown in the following picture.

After you initialized the Git repository, you either add files or directly commit them to the Git repository.

I hope this would be helpful to you. Let me know if anything wrong.
Useful URL: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#initialize

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I has already installed Git plugin. The solution was just to close and open Netbeans... pretty simple.